# Numerical integration in Matlab using polar coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

I have a set of points givven in polar coordinates which suppose to lie on the perimeter of a circle. I would like to calculate the surface of the circle that is most close to the form the points create. if this is not possible, I would at least want to get the surface of the polygon created by the points. 
the motivation for this is to calculate pi assuming the points do create a circle (or at least an ellipse).

Is there a Matlab function for this operation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: i wrote what is the point of the question, but im really clueless about how to do it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to fit a circle to the data points and find the area of the circle?

Comment: yes, this is what i want

Comment: I don't think there is a Matlab command that does it. You might want to check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8974849/least-squares-circle-fitting-using-matlab-optimization-toolbox

Comment: I wrote a suite of Matlab functions related to reliably fitting data points to a circle a few years ago – you can download the M-files [here](http://biorobots.cwru.edu/personnel/adh/math.se/06/), in particular the `circfit` function. All functions include documentation.